# How to expand the volume of Fedora 35 Server?

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, partition, fedora

#### Perspectives

---

Actually I was looking for **Pi OS** AArch64 but it was a beta version. It's suppose to me [**Fedora 35 Server**](https://fedora.ipserverone.com/fedora/linux/releases/35/Server/aarch64/images/) AArch64 would be the best alternative of **Pi OS** AArch64. Actually [**Fedora 35 Server**](https://fedora.ipserverone.com/fedora/linux/releases/35/Server/aarch64/images/) AArch64 needed to build **Quarkus** AArch64 native image using **Podman**.

It was the first time [**Fedora 35 Server**](https://fedora.ipserverone.com/fedora/linux/releases/35/Server/aarch64/images/) AArch64 downloaded and written into a **Samsung 32GB EVO Plus** micro SD card using [**Raspberry Pi Imager**](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/). It was a very easy installation but there were some strict dependencies with some external peripheral like **HDMI Monitor**, **Micro HDMI Converter** & **Keyboard**.

Fortunately I able to manage those peripherals. Unfortunately I unable to bypass this installation and configuration process over the **ethernet** using **SSH** like **Pi OS**.

So far I can remember, I never have to use any external peripherals like **HDMI Monitor**, **Micro HDMI Converter** or **Keyboard** to install or configure **Pi OS**. Only I have to rely on existing **WiFi Router** & **CAT6** ethernet cable.

#### Configurations

---

This the first time I've to use such peripheral devices instead of **CAT6** ethernet cable. I'm a bit worried as it might not be cost effective for the beginners as well for the learners. Anyway I was able to install and configure [**Fedora 35 Server**](https://fedora.ipserverone.com/fedora/linux/releases/35/Server/aarch64/images/) AArch64 as following:

```bsh
sudo nmcli dev wifi rescan
sudo nmcli dev wifi
sudo nmcli dev

sudo nmcli dev wifi con 'ChorkeOrg_2.4GHz' password 'sadaqah!'
sudo nmcli dev wifi con 'ChorkeOrg' password 'sadaqah!'
sudo nmcli con

sudo timedatectl set-timezone 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname fedora
sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```

`disable_overscan=1` added at the end of the line of `/boot/efi/config.txt` to disable overscan. It will be reduced booting time. After reboot I able to access the cockpit [https://fedora:9090/](https://10.20.21.10:9090/).

#### Issue: Volume Resize

---

But I disappointed a bit when I can't utilize the total space of **Samsung 32GB EVO Plus**. Please find the details as following:

```bsh
lsblk
:'
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mmcblk0                179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1            179:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2            179:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p3            179:3    0  5.4G  0 part 
  └─fedora_fedora-root 253:0    0  5.4G  0 lvm  /
zram0                  252:0    0  7.6G  0 disk [SWAP]
'
```

Would you please guide us how to expand physical volume of `/dev/mmcblk0p3` as well logical volume of `/dev/fedora_fedora/root`?

Comment: The same way you would resize an ext4 partition on any linux system: `fdisk` to resize the partition itself then `resize2fs` to resize the filesystem on it.  You can also use the GUI tool `gparted`.   This doesn't really need to be regurgitated in detail again here as it surely is already dozens of times online, but someone may come along who wants to bother.

Comment: BTW, anything significant that's wrong with the RpiOS 64-bit beta version will be wrong with Fedora because they are issues with the kernel and pi specific software, and those will be the same. This is probably a waste of time (my preferred distro is Fedora, but I stopped using it on Pis after a while, the added hassles are not worth the added benefits).

Comment: Actually [**Fedora 35 Server AArch64 Raw Image**](https://fedora.ipserverone.com/fedora/linux/releases/35/Server/aarch64/images/) comes with **XFS** (Linux File System). **XFS** compatible with `fdisk`, `parted` but issue raised for `resize2fs` with message _**Bad magic number in super-block**_

Comment: Huh. Sometimes they are a bit silly IMO.  Anyway, as the name was meant to imply (and a quick check of the man page would reveal), `resize2fs` is for use  with ext2/3/4 filesystems.  But 15 seconds with google ("resize xfs") tells me the equivalent command is `xfs_growfs`.

Comment: ...If you get this to work please leave an answer of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to resize the partition for **Physical Volume**. It's can be done by so many ways but those are newbie like me can follow those steps as following:

#### Resize the Partition

---

```bsh
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
:'
Command (m for help): p
Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-3, default 3): 3

Command (m for help): n
Select (default p): p
Partition number (3,4, default 3): 3
First sector (3328000-62521343, default 3328000): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (3328000-62521343, default 62521343): 
Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N

Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1-3, default 3): 3
Hex code or alias (type L to list all): 8e

Command (m for help): p
Command (m for help): w
'
```

Then we need to expand **Physical & Logical Volume** as following:

#### Status: Before Expand

---

```bsh
lsblk
:'
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mmcblk0                179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1            179:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2            179:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p3            179:3    0 28.2G  0 part 
  └─fedora_fedora-root 253:0    0  5.4G  0 lvm  /
zram0                  252:0    0  7.6G  0 disk [SWAP]
'
```

#### Expand: Physical Volume

---

```bsh
sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0p3
sudo pvresize /dev/mmcblk0p3 
sudo pvs
```

#### Expand: Logical Volume

---

```bsh
sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/fedora_fedora/root
sudo xfs_growfs /dev/fedora_fedora/root
sudo lvs
```

#### Status: After Expand

---

```bsh
lsblk
:'
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mmcblk0                179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1            179:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2            179:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p3            179:3    0 28.2G  0 part 
  └─fedora_fedora-root 253:0    0 28.2G  0 lvm  /
zram0                  252:0    0  7.6G  0 disk [SWAP]
'
```

Finally our **Physical & Logical Volume** updated. Before reboot we needs to verify partitions using `mount -a`. If there is no more issue found then we can reboot our system.

#### Remount & Reboot

---

```bsh
sudo mount -a
sudo init 6
```

Comment: I voted this up, but I suggest you rename "Memory Re-Allocation" to something else. It's definitely true that people call flash, which this happens to be "memory", but here it's really serving as a "drive", and I think calling it "memory" is too easy to confuse with "RAM".